# Need to know if user is coming from frontpage using jquery

Tags: javascript

On a Drupal 7 site I need some jQuery-animation on a page, only if user is coming directly from frontpage. My programming skills are very limited and need some help on that. I found something with parent.history.back()-function, but I don't know if and how I can use that in an if-statement.
Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var referrer =  document.referrer;
  if (referrer == 'http://domain.tld/') {
    // Make whatever you like  
  }
});
```